# Validating xml against schema with libxmljs2

Tags: typescript, xml, xsd, libxml-js

I am trying to validate a generated XML Document using libxmljs2 (seems to be the best tool for the job in Typescript), but`document.validate()` keeps throwing 'Invalid XML Schema' errors at me, without further explanation.

When an XML does not conform to a XSD, it gives detailed errors, but it says nothing about the XSD when it cannot handle it.

I tried to go 1 level up and asked libxmljs2 to validate my XSD (which is fine, according to XMLSpy at least) against the XML Schema Definition, I'm getting the same error. Maybe it was a silly test, and libxmljs2 cannot handle the XML Schema Definition for some reason.

But the bottom line is : I can't seem to have any information on what's going wrong when trying to validate my XML with this lib.

```js
const xsdPath = path.join(__dirname, '/xsd/');
const xsd = parseXmlString(fs.readFileSync(path.join(xsdPath, 'my.xsd'), 'utf8'), { baseUrl: xsdPath });
try {
  const valid = xmlDocument.validate(xsd);  // throws
  if (!valid) {
    console.error(`XML is not valid against the XSD: ${JSON.stringify(this.doc.validationErrors)}`) 
  }
}
catch (e) {
  console.error('I end up here. validate() throws an error about "invalid XML Schema"');
}
```

Please note that:

- xsdPath is correct, contains my .xsd files, and does end with a '/'
- I use the baseUrl option to circumvent the file loading problem. I tried changing the current working dir too, same issue

Comment: The schema https://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd imports the schema http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd, at least. Anyway, validating a schema against the schema for schemas is usually not necessary to check a schema, you just compile it with the validator. Although I have no idea whether/how that would work with that particular API.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> XMLSchema.xsd is w3c's XML Schema definition. This is a fairly simple
> schema, without includes

Actually the schema-for-schema-documents is very far from simple, because it defines things like the primitive types (for example it declares `<xs:simpleType name="hexBinary">`) which is something that requires special privileges: a normal schema isn't allowed to change these definitions. So some schema processors cannot handle this "metaschema", or need special configuration options to allow it.

But the question is, why are you even doing this? The way to check that your schema is valid is to throw it at a schema processor, not to validate it against the schema-for-schema-documents.

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't need this. I am trying to understand why libxmljs2 can't validate my XML document against it corresponding schema.
But the only piece of information I have is the error: 'Invalid XML schema'.

Why does libxmljs2 says my schema (not my XML, the corresponding XSD) is invalid ? I used XMLSpy to control it and it says it's ok. It doesn't seem to be the "included-file-not-found" problem that some people experienced and reported, as I did the necessary to handle it (in 2 different ways).

Comment: My conjecture is that libxml can't handle the schema-for-schema-documents, on the grounds that it does some things that ordinary schemas aren't allowed to do, like defining types in the XSD namespace. But that's only a conjecture. I know that getting the Saxon schema processor to accept the S4SD required quite a bit of special casing.